# VB.net function that returns an object that is specified by the input

Tags: vb.net, function, object

I am trying to write a function that returns a newly created object ( a form ) that is specified by the input. I'm having trouble with how to work out the concept of giving a type as an input then creating an object of that type in the body of the function. Here is an outline of what I'm working on.

```
Public Function MakeMyForm(ByVal frmType as Form) as Form
  Dim NewObj as New frmType
  Return NewObj
End Function
```

I'd like to be able to call the function in this way:

```
Dim myform as CustomFormType
myform = MakeMyForm(CustomFormType)
```

Can my concept be accomplished in VB.net?

Comment: why do that for a form?  It will take more code to support this, than it takes to just create the form outright.

Comment: I have to agree with Plutonix.  What do you gain by doing that instead of simply `Dim myform As New CustomFormType`?

Comment: @jmcilhinney: After I tested my initial answer, I had a "Do'h" moment and realized the same thing - however, maybe there's more that the op intended to happen in the MakeMyForm method, but even then you could instantiate first and call another method. Then again, maybe the intent is self-obfuscating code...

Comment: There is more to the project. I do realize that I could just create the instance but, I have a common set of validation code that I want to run for many forms. I thought that if I could have a function generate the form then I could reuse my validation code. The validation code is meant to check for other instances and reuse them if they are available. Therefor, I need to run the validation before creating the new instance of the form.

Comment: Just to add a bit more detail. In the validation code I look for an instance of the intended form and if found would like to return a reference to it, otherwise, generate a new instance and return a reference to that instead.

Comment: You might want to edit your post and explain more by what you mean by *validation code*.  To me, at least, it means validating the data on the form, not checking form instances.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, if I understand you, you just want a generic method:

```
Public Function MakeMyForm(Of T As {New, Form})() As T
    Return New T()
End Function
```

and call it like this:

```
Dim myform As CustomFormType = MakeMyForm(Of CustomFormType)()
```

of course, why wouldn't you just use:

```
Dim myform As New CustomFormType()
```

Comment: good answer and I couldnt tolerate seeing it sitting below the other one

Comment: @Plutonix: Thanks! But my answer is probably overkill since the direct instantiation (last line) is probably all that's needed (as pointed out by jmcilhinney).

Comment: That was my point to the OP in my comment.  Even more cruft comes in to play when you try to reference controls.

Comment: I added a comment to my OP to explain why I am exploring the original idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this:

```
Dim frmnew() As Form
Dim createdforms As Integer = 0

Private Sub createform(wintext As String, height As Integer, width As Integer, backcolor As Color, topmost As Boolean, formborderstyle As FormBorderStyle, winstate As FormWindowState, opacity As Decimal, startposition As FormStartPosition, enabled As Boolean) 'add as many properties as you like
    ReDim Preserve frmnew(createdforms)
    frmnew(createdforms) = New Form
    With frmnew(createdforms)
        .Text = wintext
        .Height = height
        .Width = width
        .BackColor = backcolor
        .TopMost = topmost
        .FormBorderStyle = formborderstyle
        .WindowState = winstate
        .Opacity = opacity
        .StartPosition = startposition
        .Enabled = enabled
    End With
    frmnew(createdforms).Show()
    createdforms += 1
End Sub
```

and you can test it with the code below:

```
createform("Afnan Makhdoom", 500, 700, Color.Aqua, False, Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D, FormWindowState.Normal, 0.9, FormStartPosition.CenterScreen, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Public Function Makemyform(ByVal frmType As Form) As Form
        Dim obj As Form
        obj = newfunc(frmType)
        Return obj
    End Function
    Public Function newfunc(ByVal mytype As Form) As Form
        Return New Form
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done using generics in a function such as:

```
Public Function GetItem(Of T)(key As String) As T
```

Usage:

```
myIntVar = myFoo.GetItem(Of Int32)(bar)
```

The purpose of which is for the code calling it to specify how it needs the return.  In the above a whole bunch of data has been serialized and the original Type lost, so when fetching it back, the `Of T` helps convert it rather than using `Object` as the return.

For forms, it is more problematic:

```
Public Function MakeAForm(Of T)() As Form   ' cant do As T
```

You'd have to add more code to cast Form to Form1 or frmCust to avoid `tbName is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.Form` errors.  Even the correct way as shown by Mr Dokjnas present problems trying to do more with the form:

```
Public Function MakeAForm(Of T As {New, Form})() As T

    Dim frm As New T
    If frm.GetType Is frm8088.GetType Then

        frm.textbox1.text = "ziggy"       ' error
    End If
    Return frm
```

Here, it is 'TextBox is not a member of T`.  If your forms were compiled to a ClassLib so the IDE could know more about the Types (forms) you could get it to work.  But the first sign of futility is revealed in using it:

```
    Dim frm As Form = MakeAForm(Of frm8100VI)()
    frm.Show()
```

It takes more code to call the FormMaker than to just create an instance.

Comment: The reason I came up with the concept was that I will have a bunch of forms that all need the same validation code run before they are generated. I was going to build that validation code into the function that creates the form. Would the method you described above be efficient for that purpose?